# Getting a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:" error everytime I click on a <asp:ImageButton />

Tags: c#, asp.net, jscript

Help!

I have a GridView with an `<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>` combination. Inside this combination I have an `<asp:ImageButton ...>` It looks nice but everytime I click on this button I get an error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 500

I don't even get to the event that button fires.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="PuckGridView" 
    runat="server" 
    EmptyDataText="Sorry, no data available"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    Font-Size = "X-Small" 
    Width = "1150px"
    Height = "410px"
    onselectedindexchanged="PuckGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    onrowcommand="RowUserActivity" 
    onpageindexchanging="PuckGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowdatabound="PuckGridView_RowDataBound" 
    GridLines="Horizontal"
    onsorting="PuckGridView_Sorting"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" ForeColor="Black" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Status" HeaderText="Status">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" +  Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>' CommandName="UpdateStatus" />
                <%-- <asp:Image ID="statusImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" +  Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>' />--%>
                <asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StatusText") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="onCallImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" + DisplayCorrectOnCallImage(Eval("OnCallImage")) %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenEmail" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Email") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenUserName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFirstName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenLastName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" Visible="true" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="LastName" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" Visible="true" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="OfficePhone" HeaderText="Phone" Visible="true" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="TeamRole" DataField="TeamRole" HeaderText="Team/Role" Visible="true" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Location" DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" Visible="true" />
        <asp:ButtonField  HeaderText="Mail" ButtonType="Image" CommandName="SendMail" ImageUrl="~/Images/mail.gif" Visible="true"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Image ID="imgHours" ToolTip=' <%# Eval("Hours") %> ' ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/clock.gif"  %>' runat="server" />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" Visible="true" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you run this app in the VS debugger? That should catch the server-side exception. You could also try looking into your server logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if there are any invalid html tags. or try viewstate=false

Comment: I removed some suspicious un-needed tags and that solved the problem!!!
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
 <%-- <asp:Image ID="statusImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" +  Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>' />--%>
```

I have had troubled with commented things in templates previously

Also check your

```
 onselectedindexchanged="PuckGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

event as this may also fire when you click on the row

Comment: I did remove the comment to no avail. 
The PuckGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(...) event is called everytime the user clicks on the row but I use the CommandName to fix that issue.
Thanks!